# Dashboard - How to make a component show the largest single sale from an opportunity (closed won)?

Tags: dashboard, charts, custom-reports

How can I make a component show the largest sale for the calendar month?

It's for one team - they want to see who had the largest sale of the month.

Every time I try to build a report & then use the chart as a component it insists on using record count as one of the axis instead of just showing

> Dave Smith = £50,000
>
> Gina Smith = £30,000

I just want to show a sort of leaderboard for the month. Not how much they have accumulated over the month but which specific opportunity was the largest sale

Comment: Group By rep and MAX the The Opp value at the rep level

Comment: Cheers buddy xx

Comment: Did that do it for you? If so i will add as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run a query independent of any report where you find each user's opp that is closed-won with the highest opp amount, then put the results in a table that your component creates. This will always be up to date regardless of whether a report has been run.

You sort by amount (Max) per user for each month queried which allows you to populate the table. This will be an aggregate results query using aliases. If you include multiple months, you may need to do this using a GroupBy clause (groupBy month) with Desc on MAX Amount for User. I don't think using a report will be the most efficient solution for a component.